# jQuery if selected, create a dropdown based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a multi-select drop-down where I select different opinions and based on the options, it generates different dropdowns.

```js
$('#select').change(
  function() {
    $('#ulSelect').empty();
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(
      function() {
        $('<li />').text($(this).text()).attr('data-value', this.value).appendTo($('#ulSelect'));
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="select" name="select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>

<ul id="ulSelect"></ul>
```

This snippet makes something similar to what i want, but here it is generating li elements. with this line of code
 `$('<li />').text($(this).text()).attr('data-value',this.value).appendTo($('#ulSelect'));` I believe.

How could this generate another drop-down with an id containing the selected value.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a `<select>` to each `<li>` when you create it.

```js
$('#select').change(
  function() {
    $('#ulSelect').empty();
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
      var select = $("<select>", { // create a <select> with a name depending on the option
        name: "select-" + this.value
      });
      // Add an initial option to the <select>
      select.append("<option value=''>Please select " + this.textContent + "</option>");
      // here you can add other options as appropriate
      $('<li/>', { // Create a <li> to hold the <select>
        html: select
      }).appendTo($('#ulSelect')); // And append it to the <ul>
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="select" name="select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
    <option value="e">e</option>
</select>

<ul id="ulSelect"></ul>
```

Comment: I would like that it generated many dropdowns, not just one with the selected values

Comment: What should be in each dropdown?

Comment: nothing specific at the moment. could be just "first item", "second item", etc

Comment: it does exactly what I wanted, but could you explain a bit what each part does?

Comment: `$("<select>")` creates a `<select>`, with attributes coming from the object argument. `select.append("<option...>")` appends an `<option>` to the `<select>`.